# Is it possible to append value in an existing object - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, append

Consider i am having an object "req".

**When i use console.log(req) i get**

```
Object { term="s"}
```

**My requirement is to append an value with the existing object.**

My expected requirement is to be like this:

```
Object { term="s", st_id = "512"}
```

Is it possible to do the above?

If yes, how ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to do it;

Plain javascript:

```
var req = { "term" : "s" };
req.st_id = "512";
```

Because javascript objects behaves like associative arrays[*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) you can also use this:

```
var req = { "term" : "s" };
req["st_id"] = "512";
```

jQuery way [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var req = { "term" : "s" };
$.extend(req, { "st_id" : "512" });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a couple of ways:

```
req.st_id = "512";
```

**or**

```
req["st_id"] = "512";
```

The second of these is especially useful if the variable name is dynamic, e.g. a variable could be used instead of the string literal:

```
var key = "st_id";
req[key] = "512";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, to add properties to a value simply use the following syntax:

```
req.st_id = "512";
```